# Possible to detect double click on a JComboBox item?

Tags: java, swing, listener, jcombobox

I have a question for school that states I should change the background color of my `JFrame` when "an item in the `JComboBox` is double clicked".

Is this possible using an `ItemListener` or `ActionListener`? Or would I need to implement using a `MouseListener`?

Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class ColorSelection extends JFrame {

    String[] colorNames = {
            "Black", "Blue"
    };
    Color colors[] = {
            Color.BLACK, Color.BLUE
    };
    JComboBox coloursComboBox = new JComboBox(colorNames);
    ColorItemListener colorItemListener = new ColorItemListener(this);

    public ColorSelection() {
        super("My color combobox");

        coloursComboBox.addItemListener(colorItemListener);

        add(coloursComboBox, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        setSize(600, 600);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ColorItemListener implements ItemListener {

        ColorSelection colorSelection;

        public ColorItemListener(ColorSelection colorSelection) {
            this.colorSelection = colorSelection;
        }

        @Override
        public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
            if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
                if (e.getItem().toString().equals("Black")) {
                    colorSelection.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
                } else {
                    colorSelection.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ColorSelection();
    }
}
```

Comment: Double click the control or an item in the popup?

Comment: on an item in the popup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know if it is possible because the popup of the checkbox is closed after a single mouse click.

However, if it is possible, I would suggest you would need to add a MouseListener to the JList that has been added to the popup of the combo box.

After creating the combo box you can add a MouseListener to the JList with code like:

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox(...);
Object child = comboBox.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);

if (child instanceof BasicComboPopup)
{
    BasicComboPopup popup = (BasicComboPopup)child;
    JList list = popup.getList();
    list.addMouseListener(...);
}
```